# Using getpid() with clone() results in SIGSEGV

Tags: c, memory, clone

I'm trying to run a simple `clone()` using the next code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE  
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int child_func(void* arg) {

//  printf("Child is running with PID %d\n", getpid());
  printf("Child is running\n");
  return 0;  
} 

int main() {

    printf("main() started\n");

    pid_t child_pid = clone(child_func, malloc(4096), SIGCHLD, NULL);
    pid_t parent_pid = getpid();

    printf("Parent pid: %lu\n", parent_pid);
    printf("Child pid: %lu\n", child_pid);

}
```

And all good here:

> ```
> $ ./clone_example 
> main() started
> Parent pid: 9200
> Child pid: 9201
> Child is running
> ```

Until I'm changing the `child_func()` by adding the `getpid()` execution:

```
...
int child_func(void* arg) {

  printf("Child is running with PID %d\n", getpid());
//  printf("Child is running\n");
  return 0;  
} 
...
```

After re-compiling this code - the `child_func()` starts failing.

The console output looks like:

> ```
> $ ./clone_example 
> main() started
> Parent pid: 11085
> Child pid: 11086
> ```

And if run with the `strace`:

> ```
> $ strace -o clone_example.log -ff ./clone_example 
> main() started
> Parent pid: 11655
> Child pid: 11656
> ```

In the thread's log `clone_example.log.11656` I see the next:

> ```
> >     --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x562696b1dff8} ---
> >     +++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
> ```

Why so?
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`man 2 clone`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html):

> The `child_stack` argument specifies the location of the stack used by the child process.  Since the child  and
>          calling  process  may  share memory, it is not possible for the child process to execute in the same stack as
>          the calling process.  The calling process must therefore set up memory space for the child stack and  pass  a
>          pointer  to  this  space to `clone()`.  **Stacks grow downward on all processors that run Linux (except the HP PA
>          processors), so `child_stack` usually points to the topmost address of the memory space set up  for  the  child
>          stack.**

Your child is running into segmentation fault because the stack grows down and you are passing a pointer to the start of a newly allocated memory area, when you should pass a pointer to the end of such area. This only happens when you add another function call (`getpid()`) because without that call your child process is not using as much stack.

Correct call would be:

```
pid_t child_pid = clone(child_func, ((uint8_t*)malloc(4096)) + 4095, SIGCHLD, NULL);
```

PS: I'm guessing that inline call to `malloc()` was just to simplify the example, but you should check the return value of `malloc()` before passing it to the child.

Comment: You may also want to add that it's not a good practice to call the `malloc()` in the way OP is doing. Instead, call `malloc()` and check the return and if its not null then use that reference in the `clone()` argument.

Comment: @H.S. granted that, I'm guessing that code is only an example to get us to understand the problem.